# Is an QAbstractItemModel subclass thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

*Hello good ppl from SO !*

Today I have been questioning myself a lot about what I was trying to implement.

It comes to this, I'm trying code some kind a of terminal with Qt, which will be used to display messages from different parts of my application.

Right now I implemented a model class (derived from `QAbstractTableModel`) that represent a `QList` of theses message lines and was intending to map them to the widget in my Terminal window ( `DataWidgetMapper` was considered ).

But then it hit me, what if different parts of my app was trying to add at the same time new messages ?
Can it even possibly happen ?
Is implementing `BeginInsertRow` related to safe guarding theses kind of things ?

---

Long story short I'm confused. I can't find much intel on my own. So I'm starting to wonder if I'm even doing this the right way.

I'm a bit of a new guy in the Qt world.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: @tambre Of course I did. That's basically all that I was doing for the last week. 
I just didnt find anything comforting me about thread safety.
But I admit that I read so much stuff in so little time, not everything is crystal clear to me.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#an-editable-model
Sure that's helpful, but it doesn't soothe my worries

Comment: There being different "parts" of your application doesn't imply that there are multiple threads, not unless you added them yourself. Are you actually accessing the model from multiple threads? If you're not, then the question is moot. You're not using the word *thread* anywhere but in the title, so I'm skeptical whether your application is truly multi-threaded, or whether you somehow assume that threads pop up behind your back.

Comment: It's not so much that I assumed it did, it's more that I wasn't sure it didn't. But nowthat I read all theses answers I'm starting to think that I was getting worried for nothing and understanding this a bit wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're implementing your own model on top of `QAbstractItemModel`, the determination of whether it's thread-safe is up to you. You have to design your own internal data model, so the methods that change and access data within the model are your own. You have complete control of their contents so you can add whatever thread-locking mechanism you need to ensure that different threads can't both update and access data at the same time. All of the `QAbstractItemModel` methods that provide data access end up calling your derived methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I got worked up for nothing.
I did not implemented any threads myself so I guess I won't get in any troubles

Comment: Then you're perfectly safe. :) Still, it's a good question and good to be thinking about those things.